# как получить и использовать текущее состояние в фильтре в aiogram 3

Tags: python, aiogram

в данном фильтре мне нужно сравнивать текущее машинное состояние с состоянием из списка но почему то не один из операторов сравнения не отрабатывает хотя состояние совпадает

```
class IsIHAveThisCode(BaseFilter):
    async def __call__(self, message: Message, state:FSMContext) -> bool:
        print(await state.get_state())
        if await state.get_state() == languages.PYTHON_HAVE_BEEN_GOT:

            files = os.listdir(path='python_files')
            max_file = len(files)

            try:
                for i in range(1, max_file):
                    if str(message) == str(i):
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False
            except:
                return False

        elif await state.get_state() == languages.CSHARP_HAVE_BEEN_GOT:

            files = os.listdir(path='c#_files')
            max_file = len(files)

            try:
                for i in range(1, max_file):
                    if str(message) == str(i):
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False
            except:
                return False

        elif await state.get_state() is None:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

всё я разобрался, кому нужно вот рабочий вариант

```
class IsIHAveThisCode(BaseFilter):
    async def __call__(self, message: Message, state:FSMContext) -> bool:
        if await state.get_state() == languages.PYTHON_HAVE_BEEN_GOT:
            print(await state.get_state())
            files = os.listdir(path='python_files')
            max_file = len(files)
            try:
                for i in range(1, max_file + 1):
                    if str(message.text) == str(i):
                        return True
            except:
                return False

        elif await state.get_state() == languages.CSHARP_HAVE_BEEN_GOT:
            print(await state.get_state())
            files = os.listdir(path='c#_files')
            max_file = len(files)
            try:
                for i in range(1, max_file + 1):
                    if str(message.text) == str(i):
                        return True
            except:
                return False

        elif await state.get_state() is None:
            print(await state.get_state())
            return False
```

ошибки: 1 функцию get_state у обьекта `FSMcontext` нужно вызывать с помощью `await`
2 в строке `if str(message) == str(i):` нужно обращаться не к `message` а к `message.text` 3 нужно убрать строку `else: return False` в цикле